# Shading 25 squares within a square using `\foreach`

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

In a square of edge length `5*sqrt(2)`, I have 45 congruent squares of edge length `sqrt(2)` drawn. I would like to shade 25 of them - 5 of them in each row. I shaded the 5 squares in the bottom row and started shading the other rows. How can I do this using `\foreach`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%A square with edge length 5*sqrt(2) is drawn. With ten line segments of slope 1 and
%ten line segments of slope -1, 45 squares with edge length sqrt(2), sixteen isosceles
%right triangles with legs of length sqrt(2), and four isosceles right triangles with
%legs of length sqrt(2)/2 are drawn. Twenty-five of the squares are shaded.
%(The figure is scaled by 1/4.)
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},0) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- (0,{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},0) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)},0) -- ({(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2))}) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)},0) -- ({(1/4)*(8*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- ({(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(9*sqrt(2)/2)},0) -- ({(1/4)*(10*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- ({(1/4)*(9*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(8*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
%
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- (0,{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(8*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
%
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- (0,{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
%
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(8*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- (0,{(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(6*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(4*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(3*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(8*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(7*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
%
\path[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(8*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*(9*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*(10*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- (0,{(1/4)*(9*sqrt(2)/2)}) -- cycle;
%
%
\draw (0,0) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))},0) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))}) -- (0,{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))}) -- cycle;
%
%
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5} {\draw (0,{(1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2) - (2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2))},{(1/4)*5*sqrt(2)});}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5} {\draw ({(1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)},0) -- ({(1/4)*5*sqrt(2)},{(1/4)*5*sqrt(2) - (1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)});}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5} {\draw (0,{(1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)}) -- ({(1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)},0);}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5} {\draw ({(1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)},{(1/4)*5*sqrt(2)}) -- ({(1/4)*5*sqrt(2)},{(1/4)*(2*\x - 1)*(sqrt(2)/2)},0);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know `\draw (a,b) rectangle (c,d);`? It could be useful.

Comment: Is it necessary to use exactly those lengths? Or only the shape is important? You can rotate the squares also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,8}{%
\foreach \x in {0,2,...,8}{%
\draw[fill=black!50,xshift=\x cm, yshift=\y cm]%
   (0:1cm) -- (90:1cm) -- (180:1cm) -- (270:1cm) -- cycle;
}%
}%
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle (9,9);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Edit:** the same visual result but with counters in range `0,1,2,3,4` which easily is seen to have 5 values.

```
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,4}{%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}{%
\draw[fill=black!50,xshift=\x cm, yshift=\y cm] 
      (0:.5cm) -- (90:.5cm) -- (180:.5cm) -- (270:.5cm) -- cycle;
}%
}%
\draw (-.5,-.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);
```

Comment: @Sebastiano, I think you can improve and use your sqrt length. I used polar coordinates.

Comment: This is some seriously concise code for my diagram!

Comment: Do you have to add units to `xshift` and `yshift`?

Comment: The diagram is too big. Can I have `xshift={(1/4)*\x}` and `yshift={(1/4)*\y}`?

Comment: You can use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]` for example, just to change the size. But, if you really need some exact measure, some adjustment should be done.

Comment: I would prefer not to use `scale=0.5`.

Comment: I used `xshift={(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2*\x * 1cm}` and `xshift={(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2*\y * 1cm}`.

Answer (score 16):

How can I resist to this golf challenge !

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach~in{0,...,24}
      \fill[shift={({mod(~,5)+.5},{div(~,5)})},gray,rotate=45]rectangle(45:1);
    \draw rectangle(5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** A second code that is 2 characters longer but use a single loop with only 5 iterates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[gray,even odd rule,rotate=45]
        foreach~in{1,3,...,9}{(~-10,-~)rectangle(10-~,~)};
      \draw(45:-10)rectangle(45:10);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: LOL, 30 days will go by quickly

Comment: +.5 for brevity, +.5 for clever username!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you can remove .5 now ;)

Answer (score 7):

Similar to @Sigur's answer, just using your length conventions (in case you want to add something in the same conventions).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Y in {0,...,4}
{\foreach \X in {0,...,4}
{\draw[fill=gray!50] ({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2+(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\X},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\Y}) -- 
({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)+(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\X},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2+(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\Y}) -- 
({(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2+(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\X},{(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)+(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\Y}) -- 
({(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\X},{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2+(1/4)*(2*sqrt(2)/2)*\Y}) -- cycle;}}
%
\draw (0,0) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))},0) -- ({(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))},{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))}) -- (0,{(1/4)*(5*sqrt(2))}) -- cycle;
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I appreciate that you kept so much of my code.

Comment: I did not know that `\x` and `\y` could be used in the `\draw` options of `xshift` and `yshift`. So, I am going to select Sigur's response.

Answer (score 5):

with use `fit` tikz library and rotated nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, fill=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=0.707106cm,
              rotate=45}
                        ]
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
\foreach \y in {0,...,4}
\node (g\x\y)   [box=gray!50]  at (\x,\y) {};
}
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt,
      fit=(g00.north west) (g00.south west)
          (g44.north east) (g44.south east)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! With nodes it is easy to insert text also.

Answer (score 4):

196 characters

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \clip[draw]rectangle(45:5);\def~{.5cm}\pgfsetdash{~~}{-~/2}
    \draw[line width=~,gray,rotate=45](0,-2)grid(5,2);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TikzerWoods I also found that `\pgfsetdash{~}{-~/2}` = `\pgfsetdash~{-~/2}` works. But this is not documented.

Answer (score 3):

à la LL+graphicx way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0cm}% for checking
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{picture}(5,5)(0,0)
\color{gray!50}%
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){5}{%
    \begin{picture}(5,1)(0,0)
      \multiput(0,0)(1,0){5}
      {\rotatebox{45}
        {\rule{0.707106\unitlength}{0.707106\unitlength}}%
      }%
    \end{picture}%
  }%
\end{picture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: with contours as per request in comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0cm}% for checking
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{picture}(5,5)(0,0)
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){5}{%
    \begin{picture}(5,1)(0,0)
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
      \multiput(0,0)(1,0){5}
      {\rotatebox{45}
        {\fbox{\color{gray!50}%
               \rule{0.707106\unitlength}{0.707106\unitlength}}}%
      }%
    \end{picture}%
  }%
\end{picture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet better with this replacement

```
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-.5\fboxrule}%
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. But unfortunately, no contour in squares. :)

Comment: @Sigur updated :)

Comment: btw, English term is 'border' not 'contour'. :)

Comment: @jfbu, perfect!! And amazing.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I confess I was not comfortable with that word but it was the only one which came to my mind... lol

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, this is how to draw the figure using MetaPost. I use ConTeXt, but the code should also work with LaTeX (using the `emp` package in pdflatex and `mplib` package in lualatex).

```
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=2mm]
  n := 5;

  path box;      box   := unitsquare rotated 45 scaled 1cm;
  numeric shift; shift := xpart(lrcorner box - llcorner box);

  for i = 0 upto (n-1) :
      for j = 0 upto (n-1) :
          fill box shifted (i*shift, j*shift) withcolor 0.8white;
          draw box shifted (i*shift, j*shift) withcolor black;
      endfor
  endfor

  draw unitsquare scaled (n*shift) xshifted -shift/2;


\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not a `matrix of nodes` with `diamond` nodes?

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[draw, inner sep=0pt, 
            matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
            column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt, 
            nodes={diamond, draw, fill=gray!50, minimum size={1cm*sqrt(2)}}]
    {&&&&\\&&&&\\&&&&\\&&&&\\&&&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]